# Display data in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have two tables on the `SSRS` report which displays data depending on the results returned by a single dataset.
The second table displays a subset of data which is displayed on the first depending on some parameters.Now I would like to implement a functionality which displays "`no rows`" in the second table if the `countrows=0` (subset returned from first table) and display the data(subset of data in the first table) if the `countrows>0`

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 11):

There is a property on the table called "NoRows" that allows you to enter any text you want to show if there are no rows returned.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can also use this solution:
for your `dataset2` click the tablix and at the bottom you shall have Row groups. Click on each of the row groups. So if you have 1 child and 1 parent you will have to do this on both.
1) Right click group_child->group properties->filters and put the following expression `"=IsNothing(Fields!Group_Child.Value)="True"" "`; set it as boolean expression and `'value'='False'` and you will have to do same for Group_parent1 thru n.
This will display NO rows if you have NO data for bottom dataset. If this is the same thing you want to do with Tablix 1 go for it.